# Java 9 Cleaner Correct Usage

Tags: java, garbage-collection, resources

Reading about Java 9's [Cleaner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) class, I found this example in the same page:

```java
public class CleaningExample implements AutoCloseable {
    // A cleaner, preferably one shared within a library
    private static final Cleaner cleaner = <cleaner>;

    static class State implements Runnable {

        State(...) {
            // initialize State needed for cleaning action
        }

        public void run() {
            // cleanup action accessing State, executed at most once
        }
    }

    private final State;
    private final Cleaner.Cleanable cleanable

    public CleaningExample() {
        this.state = new State(...);
        this.cleanable = cleaner.register(this, state);
    }

    public void close() {
        cleanable.clean();
    }
}
```

In the second line there is a comment saying:

> A cleaner, preferably one shared within a library

Why is it preferable to have one shared `Cleaner` (static) within a library?

Does anybody have a good example about how to use `Cleaner` instead of overriding `finalize()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is it preferable to have one shared Cleaner (static) within a library?

A cleaner has an associated thread. Threads are limited native resources. So the goal is to limit the amount of Threads created by not creating more cleaners than necessary.

> Does anybody have a good example about how to use Cleaner instead of overriding finalize()?

You posted the reference example. You need to ask more specific questions if that is insufficient.

Comment: That's quit what I wanted to understand. So unlike finalization blocks the developer has control over the `Thread` in which a `Cleaner` runs.

Comment: @M.S. there’s more to it. Note that `CleaningExample` implements `AutoCloseable`, hence, can be used in a `try(…)` statement. If you use that, cleaning is done immediately at the end of the block and the garbage collector becomes irrelevant. That’s different to `finalize()`, which you can’t cancel, so when using `finalize()`, you have to live with the fact that the object needs to get collected twice, once before `finalize()` and again afterwards, even if there’s nothing to do, when the code using the resource did call `close()`.

Comment: I also suspected that in this example `Cleaner` will act like Plan B.

Answer (score 2):

The docs do explicitly mention:

> The choice of a new cleaner or sharing an existing cleaner is determined by the use case.

Also:

> Each cleaner operates independently, managing the pending [...]

which implies multiple `Cleaner` instances are allowed within an application.

Again, since the factory method `Cleaner::create` is provided and is documented as

> Returns a new Cleaner.

I do not see why only one `Cleaner` per application should be used, although the comment definitely states otherwise.

---

By surfing the web for a minute I found a few examples ( e.g [this article](http://www.enyo.de/fw/notes/java-finalization-revisited.html) ), and all use a `static` Cleaner for each `AutoCloseable` sub-class.

```
private final static Cleaner cleaner = Cleaner.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late reply but hopefully this could help somebody struggling with understanding Java Cleaners, the first part your of question was rightly answered, I will provide a simple example of directly replacing a finalizer with a cleaner. Firstly I will mention a few points you need to grasp, these outline the fundamental differences between the two

1. Finalizers are invoked by one of Garbage Collector’s threads.  All
   you have to do is override the Object class’s finalize method and
   put  your finalizing logic there.
2. You as a programmer don’t have the control of when and what thread
   will invoke the method, or even whether your finalizing logic will
   run at all
3. With cleaners, together with their cleaning logic, all objects that
   want to do some cleaning actions have to register themeselves with a
   cleaner object.
4. Unlike with finalizers, with cleaners programmers have control of
   the thread that invoke the cleaning logic.
5. Programmers can also explicitly invoke the cleaning
   actions(considered to be the best practice), in this case the
   corressponding cleaner object will not invoke the cleaning action
   anymore.

The class

```
public class FinalizingExample {
    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Doing some finalizing logic here");
    }
}
```

can be directly replaced with

```
public class CleaningExample {

    private final Cleaner cleaner = Cleaner.create();

    public CleaningExample() {
        cleaner.register(this, () -> System.out.println("Doing some cleaning logic here"));
    }
}
```

As you can see the cleanig action is registered as an instance of Runnable, The cleaner will invoke the your cleaning action once your object becomes phantom reachable (a.k.a no part of the application holds a reference to it).
You can also invoke the cleanig action explicitily. This way you as a programmer will have the control when to release/close say any expensive resources your object might hold. The Cleaner’ register method actually returns something very useful, an Instance of Cleanable, you can call this object’s clean method to invoke you cleaning action. Like below

```
public class CleaningExample {

    private final Cleaner cleaner = Cleaner.create();
    private final Cleaner.Cleanable cleanable;

    public CleaningExample() {
        cleanable = cleaner.register(this, () -> System.out.println("Doing some cleaning logic here"));
    }

//    you can call this method whenever is the right time to release resources
    public void close() {
        cleanable.clean();
    }
}
```

If you do this way the cleaner will never invoke your cleaning action again since Cleaners guarantee cleaning actions to invoked at most one time (it could well be zero.

Bear in mind that in order for cleaners to work it is a **must** that the cleaning action does **not** hold a reference to the object, if it does the object will never become phantom reachable and the whole thing will be a waste of time.

As you can see from the example that you took from the docs, the cleaning action together with the state to be cleaned are encapsulated in a static nested class exactly for this reason.

Also another thing to note. Do **not** use a lambda like I did in this example use a static nested class, I did so in order to make the example as simplest as possible and in this example the lambda does not hold any of the object fields so the lambda doe not hold a reference to the object(instance of the CleaningExample in this case), if it did it would hold its reference and the object will never become phantom reachable

Answer (score -4):

Hope it help you if using java9.

The code below was already tested in **Intellij IDEA 2017** and **oracle jdk 9**.

```
import java.lang.ref.Cleaner;

public class Main {

    public Main() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Cleaner cleaner = Cleaner.create();
            Main obj = new Main();
            cleaner.register(obj, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Hello World!222");
                }
            });
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide some explanation too

Comment: explanation: http://unitstep.net/blog/2018/03/10/java-phantomreferences-a-better-choice-than-finalize/

Comment: This is exactly the kind of code you shouldn't write.  The anonymous class here can keep a reference to its outer class, resulting in it never getting cleaned up.  The only reason it works here is that the anonymous class was created in a `static` method.  If you do this for example in a constructor this will simply not work.

Comment: It just example.....  and remenber that dont keep a ref by`new Runnable() { // closure}`

Comment: The usage of System.gc(); is not recommended by the way. It's best to let the Garbage Collector do its thing.